# How to identify server admin account name in windows Azure SQL Database

Tags: sql, azure, azure-sql-database

There are two administrative accounts (**Server admin** and **Active Directory** admin) that act as administrators. My requirement is to find out the names of these accounts. I have looked into **sys.database_principles** view and **sys.sql_logins** view but could not find anything relevant to the same. From SQL query i could not find any helpful system view to fetch the information. Can anyone please help me here?

Answer (score 1):

You can use the TSQL script below to get the **Server Admin** and **Active Directory Admin** account names.

```
SELECT [name], [type], [type_desc], [authentication_type], [authentication_type_desc] FROM sys.database_principals
WHERE (type = 'S' AND [name] != 'dbo' AND authentication_type = 1) OR 
(type = 'X' AND authentication_type = 4)
```

**Important Note:**

1. You need to run the TSQL against the **master** system database
2. Use the latest version of SQL Server Management Studio

Alternatively, you can get both account names from the Azure portal as shown below.
[image]

Reference: [Controlling and granting database access](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/sql-database/sql-database-manage-logins#unrestricted-administrative-accounts)

Comment: Actually this query returns multiple records. Try creating a sql login and then a user from this login as below
'CREATE LOGIN TestAdmin WITH PASSWORD = '<Test@tgfrg>';
create User TestAdmin from LOGIN TestAdmin'

Then execute the query given in your answer, it will return user TestAdmin also. 

From this result set, I can not tell which one is the server admin. As per my requirement, query should return only two records (As per your screenshot it should return Rick and rickb@contoso.com)

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Try this SELECT * FROM sys.sysusers
WHERE hasdbaccess = 1 AND islogin = 1 AND [name] != 'dbo'

Comment: This query also has the same issue. It returns multiple rows.